# SQL statement to count each individual NPANXX series

Tags: sql, case-when

I am writting one query where one field is DIAL_NUMBER.
some values are 11 digit and some are 10 digits in that field. where it is 11 digit i need 2nd to 7th charcter and where it is 10 digit i need 1st to 6th character.
Then i need count of each individual series. i tried with this below approach, which is giving error.
Please help me in identifying the solution.

```
select dialled number, case
when length(Dialled_Number) = '11' then Substr(Dialled_Number, 2, 7)
else Substr(Dialled_Number, 1, 6)
end
count(*)
from Error_Event
```

Comment: You need a comma after `End`, and a `Then` in your `Case`, and while it won't give an error, don't quote numerical values (`When length(Dialled_Number) = 11`)

Comment: What is your Database?

Comment: What are your expected results?  You probably need to `group by` your case statement and remove `Dialled_Number` from your `select` statement.

Comment: i have added both.. still is giving below error..   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 14 Column: 1

Comment: I need output something like below..NPANXX Count
304969 34
304969 20
848200 100
304969 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your expected results, I imagine you need to use `group by` with your query.

Perhaps something like this:

```
select case
       when length(Dialled_Number) = 11 then Substr(Dialled_Number, 2, 7)
       else Substr(Dialled_Number, 1, 6)
       end, 
    count(*)
from Error_Event
group by case
       when length(Dialled_Number) = 11 then Substr(Dialled_Number, 2, 7)
       else Substr(Dialled_Number, 1, 6)
       end
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b3d1/1)

Comment: it is giving some output.. But i need to reflect first column as either of (substr(dialled_number,1,6) or (substr(dialled_number,2,7) with counts.. Your out gave me like below.. 16123245
3049699 33
709832 3277

Comment: This answer is correct, as the question has been framed.  It is likely that you have trailing characters . . . or declared the field to be `char()` rather than `varchar()`.

Comment: Yes it is working fine.. thanks a lot.. i just need a small help to replace the column name where it is coming as when length(Dialled_Number) = 11 then Substr(Dialled_Number, 2, 6)  else Substr(Dialled_Number, 1, )     end .. I want that to be as NPANXX

Comment: I got it.. thanks Again for your help.. i really got to know about this new thing about group by case condition..

Answer (score 0):

If it is MS SQL, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT` function to get desired output.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(DIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT '81243193812' UNION
SELECT '1829321874' UNION
SELECT '182932'


SELECT NPANXX, [Count] FROM
(
    SELECT NPANXX,
    COUNT(NPANXX) OVER (PARTITION BY NPANXX) AS [Count], DIAL_NUMBER,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NPANXX ORDER BY DIAL_NUMBER) RN
     FROM
    (
        SELECT DIAL_NUMBER, 
        CASE
            WHEN LEN(DIAL_NUMBER) = 11 THEN SUBSTRING(DIAL_NUMBER,2, 7)
            ELSE SUBSTRING(DIAL_NUMBER,1, 6)
        END AS NPANXX
        FROM @table
    ) Tmp
)FTMp
WHERE RN = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bf313/1/0)